# How do I set up a "Server is overloaded" for Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

If Apache has so many users view my website...what is the best way to redirect the user to: "The server is currently getting pounded!" ?

Perhaps...analyze the # of connections? If it's over ____, redirect?

Can some-one be specific and tell me exactly what I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [mod_qos](http://mod-qos.sourceforge.net/) and configure it to failback when reaching a certain number of concurrent requests.

```
QS_LocRequestLimitDefault   200
QS_ErrorPage /overloaded.html
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution maybe use a reverse-proxy (pound, haproxy, etc) between clients and your apache servers.